# Summing up a field value across all the documents

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to sum up a field value across all the document in mongoDB, so tried the $group with null field and then `$sum`. It is giving expected result but when I same tried to convert in Java using mongoOperation then error comes saying as group value can't be null or empty.

Below is the data in my Collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c583ee7c1299106eaeec6bf"), "_class" : "com.health", "startTime" : ISODate("2019-02-04T13:02:00Z"), "endTime" : ISODate("2019-02-04T13:32:23.958Z"), "agentStatsList" : [ { "Name" : "ABC", "totalRefresh" : 103, "success" : 87, "failure" : 16 }, { "Name" : "PQR", "totalRefresh" : 19, "success" : 10, "failure" : 9 }, { "Name" : "XYZ", "totalRefresh" : 14, "success" : 13, "failure" : 1 }]}

UnwindOperation unwind=Aggregation.unwind("agentStatsList");
MatchOperation match=Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("agentStatsList.agentName").in(listOfAgents).
            and("startTime").lte(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600 * 1000)));      
GroupOperation group=Aggregation.group("").sum("agentStatsList.success").as("success").sum("agentStatsList.failure").as("failure").
sum("agentStatsList.totalRefresh").as("totalRefresh");
Aggregation aggregation=Aggregation.newAggregation(unwind,match,group);
```

Shell Query is working fine but in java its not working.

Comment: Try using any random value, like, "group". It should work the same as long as the group value is a constant.

Comment: Oh Great!!!!.It worked.Thanks a lot @AndrewNessin